# How to pass STS token through WCF Routing service?

Tags: wcf, wif, wcf-routing

I am trying to call WCF claim aware service through WCF Routing service but it gave me the following error.

"An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."

And in inner exception
"An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message."

My guess, routing can't pass/identify the tocken send from client (provided by STS).

Please provide me the workable configuration to call WIF claim aware service via WCF routing service. Really need this one.

Thanks

Mizan

Answer (score 0):

Look at the config in this [MSDN forum answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a3368f21-5b14-4de3-ae68-18c95a770217) to see how the RoutingService can be configured to "pass-thru" the message to the destination. To get a more detailed answer, you'll need to post your current configuration for the RoutingService.

Comment: I have tried different configuration but failed. I just need a configuration to pass wif claim via wcf routing. Even wcf router which will pass user information with username credentials will be helpfull.